# How can I chose what file separator Java will use?

Tags: java, file, path, filesystems

I want to generate clean path from a text generator implemented in Java.

I'm using `java.nio.file.Paths` and `java.io.File` in order to construct paths in a clear way, but they use `File.separatorChar`, that is system dependant an read-only, making the output of my generator dependant on the machine where it's executed!

How can I ask for my path to be printed with the style I chose? e.g. always print the path in the Unix's way?

Ex: `System.out.println(new Paths.get("/home/user/test.txt").getParent().toString());`

Expected output on UNIX env:

`$> /home/user`

Expected output on Windows env:

`$> /home/user`

Answer (score 1):

`Path` implements `Iterable`, so it's quite easy to do it:

```
public String toUnixPath(Path path) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(path.isAbsolute() ? "/" : "");
    for (Path element : path) 
        sb.append(element).append('/');
    return sb.toString();
}
```